# NopCommerce PropertyManager class error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I just downloaded a copy of NopCommerce from GITHUB, and tried to run it from VS2015

I am getting error in the file 'PropertyManager', below is the code. **Can some explain me exactly what it is? I guess it's a property, but not sure, because of the use of lamba.**

```
/// <summary>
/// Access object by key
/// </summary>
/// <param name="properyName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public object this[string properyName] => _propertys.ContainsKey(properyName) && CurentObject != null
    ? _propertys[properyName].GetProperty(CurentObject)
    : null;
```

Here is the file link. https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Libraries/Nop.Services/ExportImport/Help/PropertyManager.cs

Comment: start debugging and check where it produce error

Comment: add a break point on it and check what it is

Comment: The error is compile time, there is no way I can run and debug. That's the reason I want to know what does this code do/means.

Comment: what does the error say

Comment: this is a c# 6.0, this replace getter. we now come back to natation c# 5.0

Comment: I did same on my own, but was still confused to what it could be. Thanks!